# The return type 'CupertinoDatePicker' isn't a 'Future<DateTime>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: android, ios, flutter, datetime, dart

I'm trying to build an adaptative Date and Time Picker for Android and Ios,

```
DateTimeField(
    controller: date,
    focusNode: _focusNodeDate,
    validator: (value){
        if(value == null){
            return 'Ce champ est requis';
        };
        return null;
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Date de naissance',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(20),
            color: Colors.grey,
        ),
    ),
    format: format,
    onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
        if(Platform.isAndroid){
            return showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                lastDate: DateTime(2100)
            );
        } else if(Platform.isIOS) {
            return CupertinoDatePicker(onDateTimeChanged: (datetime){});
        }
    },
)
```

and I get this Error

> error: The return type 'CupertinoDatePicker' isn't a
> 'Future', as required by the closure's context.
> (return_of_invalid_type_from_closure at [app_isophro]
> lib\addProfile\addprofile.dart:232)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your widget `CupertinoDatePicker` with something that shows it and returns value, e.g:

```
showModalBottomSheet<DateTime>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => CupertinoDatePicker(onDateTimeChanged: (datetime){}))
``
```

Comment: how to add a buttom to close modalBottom like 'done' button

Comment: https://flutteragency.com/ios-like-datepicker-using-cupertinodatepicker-in-flutter/